# how to add jui autocomplete in yii2 gridview filter column

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, yii-extensions

I am trying to add jquery ui autocomplete widget in yii2 gridview with this code in the grid view filter column...

```
'filter' => AutoComplete::widget([
'model' => $searchModel,
'attribute' => 'site_id',
'clientOptions' => [
    'minLength' => 3,
    'autoFill' => true,
    'source' => new JsExpression('
        function(request, response) {
            jQuery.getJSON("'.Url::to(['site/search']).'",
            {query: request.term}, function(data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                jQuery.each(data, function(index, ele) {
                    suggestions.push({
                        label: ele.name,
                        value: ele.id
                    });
                });
                response(suggestions);
            });
        }'),
    'select' => new JsExpression('
        function(event, ui) {
            jQuery("#'.Html::getInputId($searchModel, 'site_id').'")
                .val("ui.item.value");
            jQuery("#'.Html::.'").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
        }')
],
```

]),

How to add a html hidden input element for this filter column to send the 'site_id' with grid filter query and display the jui autocomplete widget label as 'name'. Currently the 'site_id' (e.g. 2) is displayed on the filter column.

Answer (score 0):

I just add 

`. Html::hiddenInput('site_id', '')`

after the auto complete widget.